Pyspark foreach() S3 file copy and delete
I have a PySpark dataframe with currently one record in it -
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|source_file_path                                                       |destination_file_path                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Input-Data/EOBLetter/20240425/MONTHLY_EOB_69L7X7F53_20231227212740.json|Input-Data/EOBLetter/Processed/20240425/MONTHLY_EOB_69L7X7F53_20231227212740.json|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I have below function(Under class ) that is applied for each row in above dataframe using foreach()
class LoadToS3:
    def __init__(self, bucket_name, output_dir):
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.output_dir = output_dir
        # self.s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    @property
    def client(self):
        return boto3.client('s3')

    def move_files_in_s3(self, row):
        copy_source = {
            'Bucket': self.bucket_name,
            'Key': row.source_file_path
        }
        
        self.client.copy(copy_source, self.bucket_name,
                        row.destination_file_path)

        self.client.delete_object(
            Bucket=self.bucket_name,
            Key=row.source_file_path
        )

I am calling the above function with forach() -
load_to_s3 = LoadToS3(
                    self.args['SOURCE_S3_BUCKET'], self.args['DESTINATION_S3_PATH'])
s3_move_path_df.foreach(load_to_s3.move_files_in_s3)

But I am getting below error while calling above foreach()-
Following error occured: An error occurred while calling o384.isEmpty.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1374.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1374.0 (TID 5111) (100.127.190.158 executor 1): java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
File not present on S3

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate
the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by
recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Thanks @John for editing. Do you have anything to share regarding this issue ?

Error clearly says - File not present on S3, check if s3 paths are present.

Files are there and they do get copied and deleted from source, but then still it gives this error
